# Command in service runs differently if executed in terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal-services

I have a war file which I can run with: `java -jar /opt/path/to/my.war`

That same command is in a file for the service which looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/path/to/
ExecStart=/opt/path/to/jre8/jre/bin/java -jar /opt/path/to/my.war --spring.profiles.active=prod
PIDFile=/opt/path/my.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `service myservice start` the service starts as it would with the command alone. The difference is that with the `service`, loading a webpage produces an error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available!
```

The browser displays a blank page.

Note that `/opt` is only available via `sudo su`. Running the command only in `su` works. So the the problem is that something is happening differently when the service executes the command, but I dont know what..

Comment: When you run it through the service I assume it's run as root, when you run the service it's run as your user which might be the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are creating a unit file and it should be used with systemctl.
So,try this `systemctl start myservice`.

Comment: service myservice start which OrangePot mentiones will do the same on most systems